# Why decrement of variable inside loop returns no success status code?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I can't understand why inside loop with condition of equal to 0 decrementing of variable returns non-zero status code (not success) if variable was decreased to 0?

If I use a different condition for the loop - for example - until [[ $RETR -eq 1 ]] it returns 0 status code after last decreasing, the same situation for while loop or if I use let for decreasing the variable, but decreasing by ((varr--)) returns a 0 status code.

```
+ RETR=3
+ [[ 3 -eq 0 ]]
+ WRONG_COMMAND
+ [[ 127 -ne 0 ]]
+ echo 'RETRIES = 3'
RETRIES = 3
+ echo 'STATUS before decrease = 0'
STATUS before decrease = 0
+ (( --RETR ))
+ echo 'STATUS AFTER decrease = 0'
STATUS AFTER decrease = 0
+ [[ 2 -eq 0 ]]
+ WRONG_COMMAND
+ [[ 127 -ne 0 ]]
+ echo 'RETRIES = 2'
RETRIES = 2
+ echo 'STATUS before decrease = 0'
STATUS before decrease = 0
+ (( --RETR ))
+ echo 'STATUS AFTER decrease = 0'
STATUS AFTER decrease = 0
+ [[ 1 -eq 0 ]]
+ WRONG_COMMAND
+ [[ 127 -ne 0 ]]
+ echo 'RETRIES = 1'
RETRIES = 1
+ echo 'STATUS before decrease = 0'
STATUS before decrease = 0
+ (( --RETR ))
+ echo 'STATUS AFTER decrease = 1'
STATUS AFTER decrease = 1
+ [[ 0 -eq 0 ]]
+ echo 0
0
```

The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x

RETR=3

until [[ $RETR -eq 0 ]]; do
    WRONG_COMMAND 2>/dev/null
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "RETRIES = $RETR"
        echo "STATUS before decrease = $?"
        ((--RETR))
        echo "STATUS AFTER decrease = $?"
    else
        RETR=0
    fi;
done;

echo $?
```

I expect it to returns 0 status code after the variable was decreased, but it always returns 1 if the loop condition consists of equal to 0 and the variable equals 0 after decreasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exit status of `((...))` is 1 if the enclosed expression evaluates to 0, and is 1 otherwise.

When using the decrement operator, the value of the expression (and thus the exit status) depends on *when* the decrement occurs. With `--RETR`, the variable is decremented, and *then* the value of `RETR` is used. With `RETR--`, the value of `RETR` is used, *then* it is decremented.

For example:

```
$ x=1; ((x--)); echo $?  # Value of x-- is 1
0
$ x=1; ((--x)); echo $?  # Value of --x is 0
```

Comment: Note that this apparently somewhat weird behavior is explicitly to allow you to do concise things in loop conditions.  `while (( RETR-- )); do...` will encapsulate the decrement as well as the loop condition test all in one place.

Comment: Is this undocumented behavior? I can't find it in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic.

Comment: @Xypron `man bash` and `/\(\(`. It says *If the value of the expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1.*

Comment: @Xypron That link only discusses the expressions that can appear in any arithmetic context,  including  `$((...))`, `((...))`, and `${array[...]}`. The [arithmetic statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) itself  (`((...))`) is for some reason lumped together with the conditional commands.